# Advanced conditional module positions on joomla

Tags: php, module, joomla, conditional-statements

I have a box which contains three module positions inside.Now the target is when a module position loaded alone, its width should be 100% of the box; when two of the modules positions loaded, the width of each one should be 50%; and finally when all three positions loaded, apiece should be 33%.
How could I set this conditions with the least coding?
my code is now something like this:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'user1 or user2 or user3' )) : ?>
<div style="width:860px; margin:10px auto;">
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'user3' )) : ?>
   <div style="width:33%; float:left; min-height:100px;"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" style="xhtml" /></div>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'user2' )) : ?>
   <div style="width:34%; float:left; min-height:100px;"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="xhtml" /></div>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'user1' )) : ?>
   <div style="width:33%; float:left; min-height:100px;"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml" /></div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

more explain:

I think to define every special condition but in this way I don't know how to compare "three" (or more) positions with each other. i.e I know when I want to ِ Display just one of two positions (and not both of them), I should use this:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'user1 xor user2' )) : ?>>
```

But if I wanna compare one position with **two other positions at the same time**; What will be the code? somethings similar this: ?

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'user1 xor user2 or user3' )) : ?>
```

in above code I want to show **just** user1 or **only** one of user2 or user3 positions. Is it true?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than that: for a second, forget about the joomla-countModules-funkyness. Then you can get the number of Modules rather quickly:

```
$nbColumns = (bool) $this->countModules( 'user1' ) + (bool) $this->countModules( 'user2' ) + (bool) $this->countModules( 'user3' );
$widthColumn = 100.0 / $nbColumns;
```

Converting the coutModules-Return to a boolean is a shortcut for `$this->countModules( 'user1' ) ? 1 : 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this should be possible with plain HTML/CSS. I recall that if you make a table with column size "100%" and fixed width, the browser scales it automatically to comply with the number of columns:

```
<table style="width:400px;">
 <tr>
   <td width="100%">
     cell 1
   </td>
   <td width="100%">
    cell2
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I doubt this is HTML-Standard-Compliant, though ...